# I want to align my caption to the left side

Tags: floats, captions

I am writing a paper, however, i have been faced with a problem; Caption is located at the middle side of my paper and i cannot control the locus of it. (see the attached file)

[image]

the codes are;

```
\begin{figure*}[H]
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{figure_1a.pdf}
\caption{aa//left-aligned}
 \label{fig:figure_1a.pdf}
\end{figure*}
```

what should i do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE. Please so kind and provide complete small document starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `end{document}` don't forget on packages which is essential to your problem. Please help us to help you!

Comment: Why you use `figure*` if your figure seems to be placed in one column? try to use only `\begin{figure}[htb]` your figure `\end{figure}`.

Comment: Your code snippet cannot have given rise to the screenshot you've posted: The LaTeX code features `\caption{aa//left-aligned}`, yet the screenshot shows "`aaaaa`" as the figure's label. Please align the code and the screenshot to raise the odds that somebody will figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, that you like to have your image placed in one column and caption centered below image, something like this:

[image]

For this the MWE is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[htb] % <-- see difference between your code and this MWE
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}
\caption{aa//left-aligned}
    \label{fig:figure_1a.pdf}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you want to put the image inside a text or you want text and image on two different columns. If you are in the first case you can use `wrapfig` package (http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf) which helps you to manage pictures in the middle of a text. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}

    \begin{wrapfloat}{figure}{I}{0pt}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{tiRFF.png}
        \caption{This is an example}
        \label{fig: wrapfloat}
    \end{wrapfloat}
    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `threeparttable` package for that. It defines a `measuredfigure` environment, which… measures the figure, and centres the caption w.r.t. the figure width.

From the documentation of the package:

> For figures, there is an equivalent measuredfigure environment. It is fairly
>   fragile though, and should be used only for a single graphic above a single
>   caption.

I didn't test it in a two column document.

```
\usepackage{threeparttable}
.....
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{measuredfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{figure_1a.pdf}
\caption{aa//left-aligned}
 \label{fig:figure_1a.pdf}
\end{measuredfigure}
\end{figure}
```